# How to make a binary heap in C# compare based on KeyValuePair.Value?

Tags: c#

I've made a straight-forward binary heap implementation in C# for a Min/MaxHeap that takes generic type T.

How do I write logic so that if I were to insert KeyValuePair<int,int> into a MinHeap, it compares it on the KeyValuePair's Value?

For example, if the heap has two KVPs of (1, 3) and (2, 4), the MinHeap would have (1, 3) as the root.

For a more specific example, please see the code below:

```
    public static List<int> FindTopKFrequentNumbers (int[] input, int k)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        Dictionary<int, int> numCounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        MinHeap<KeyValuePair<int, int>> topK = new MinHeap<KeyValuePair<int,int>>(); // This should heapify based on Value, not Key
        
        // Build Dictionary with KeyValuePairs
        foreach (int number in input)
        {
            if (!numCounts.ContainsKey(number))
            {
                numCounts.Add(number,0);
            }
            numCounts[number]++;
        }
        
        // Find top K elements using MinHeap of size K
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> numCountPair in numCounts)
        {
            if (topK.Count < k)
            {
                topK.Push(numCountPair);
            }
            
            else
            {
                if (numCountPair.Value > topK.Peek().Value)
                {
                    topK.Pop();
                    topK.Push(numCountPair);
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Transfer to Result List
        while (topK.Count > 0)
        {
            var kvp = topK.Pop();
            result.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
        
        return result;  
    }
```

Comment: I think the generic class is probably not going to work for this case, using KeyValuePair<T, K> type. It's not like you can use your custom type that inherits from KeyValuePair<T, K> and override its equality because it's a struct. Unless there's a trick I don't know about, you would need a concrete class to handle this kind of heap implementation.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend my heap implementation so that it overloads the constructor class with a custom Comparer? I've never done it before so sorry if that's a dumb question.

Comment: @EricWu Yes.  The .NET collections that compare objects do just that.

Comment: Great! I'll try to give that a spin then.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a custom NumCountPair class that implements IComparable with a CompareTo method that compares based on NumCountPair's Count property. Then my custom MinHeap C# implementation will heapify based on NumCountPair.Count.